# Resource Designer is generated with Syntax error in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently updating our company Mobile application which was created a year back. Recently when I update my project to MonoAndroid 9.0 and build the solution I  was bombarded with many errors (attached). I tried to fix it by updating the nuget packages but after I update, Resource.Designer file has generated files with syntax errors like `public const int bottomtab.navarea = 2130969385;` where in Xamarin can't understand the "." in the above. I am also facing issues like

```
1. resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox (aka sg.totalebizsolutions.rocktree:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox) not found. CSMobile.Droid  

2. resource style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar (aka sg.totalebizsolutions.rocktree:style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.   CSMobile.Droid  

3. failed linking references.   CSMobile.Droid  

4. expected reference but got (raw string) #000000. CSMobile.Droid
```

I am not sure what am I missing here. Please find my csproj file attached

[CSProjFile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1whC_GbHYC2h5uiwPmsxDikqaRK4j-9sY/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Just delete the `ResourceDesigner` File from your project, Clean and Build it, it will be autogenerated again include it into your project and you should be good to go

Comment: I tried that like million times, still I am facing with the issue everytime new Resource Designer is generated

Comment: Do you only get issues in your Resource Designer? Nothing other than that?

Comment: I am also getting the following exception The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'CSMobile.Droid, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'CSMobile.Droid.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName). That is why I have added the csProj refereence also.

Comment: Did you update the Android Support Libraries?

Comment: this happened to me once, like @BrunoCaceiro said, Update the Support Libraries, delete Resource Designer, Rebuild and see if it resolved your problem